# how to add flag in python

Tags: python, loops

currently i have a folder that contain many files and unique text
basically there is
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

the contain of 1.txt is 111111
the contain of 2.txt is 222222
the contain of 3.txt is 333333

i have a script as below to print the contain of this txt file as below

```
from os import system
import sys

text=sys.argv[1]

def loop():
    system("cat /root/Music/loop/"+text+".txt")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop()
```

so now when i type python loop.py 1
it will print out and display 
111111

when i type python loop.py 2
it will print out and display 
222222

my question is how to i add a flag to print all?
for example python loop.py --all

111111

222222

333333

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python argparse", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: do you know all the files beforehand?

Comment: [Here's a link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to what @Prune was referring to

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parse command-line arguments in a structured way:

```
from os import system
import sys
import argparse
import os

base_dir = '/root/Music/loop'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--all', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('files', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.all:
    files = os.listdir(base_dir)
else:
    files = args.files

def print_file(path):
    system('cat ' + path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for file in files:
        print_file(os.path.join(base_dir, file))
```